# How to implement a job queue similiar to a progress board / Github Actions job runner using Vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm using Vuejs and have to execute multiple functions step by step after clicking on a button. Each job depends on the previous one so I could handle everything in a single function but I want to display the progress / give feedback.

Github Actions might be a good example for this

[image]

As already mentioned my usecase is far simpler, I know all steps in correct order and which code to execute on each step.

You can see my current [example playground implementation](https://play.vuejs.org/#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). I started with a component displaying each step

```
<script setup lang="ts">
defineProps<{
    title: string
    state: "isPending" | "isInProgress" | "isSuccessful" | "isFailed"
    error: Error | null
}>()
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <div v-if="state === 'isPending'">Step '{{ title }}': Pending</div>
    <div v-if="state === 'isInProgress'">Step '{{ title }}': In progress</div>
    <div v-if="state === 'isSuccessful'">Step '{{ title }}': Successful</div>
    <div v-if="state === 'isFailed'">Step '{{ title }}': Failed</div>
    <div v-if="state === 'isFailed'">{{ error?.message }}</div>
  </div>
</template>
```

and in the main file I added some steps with async functions to execute one by one

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref, watch } from 'vue'
import JobStep from './JobStep.vue'

interface Step {
  title: string;
  state: "isPending" | "isInProgress" | "isSuccessful" | "isFailed"
  fn: () => Promise<Error | null>;
  error: Error | null;
}

const jobSteps = ref<Step[]>([
  createNewStep("Do this", async () => {
    await new Promise(resolve => {
      setTimeout(resolve, 1000);
    });

    return null;
  }),
  createNewStep("This step might fail", async () => {
    await new Promise(resolve => {
      setTimeout(resolve, 1000);
    });

    if(Math.random() < 0.5) {
      return new Error("I failed...")
    }

    return null;
  }),
  createNewStep("Do that", async () => {
    await new Promise(resolve => {
      setTimeout(resolve, 1000);
    });

    return null;
  }),
  createNewStep("Foo", async () => {
    await new Promise(resolve => {
      setTimeout(resolve, 1000);
    });

    return null;
  }),
  createNewStep("This step might fail", async () => {
    await new Promise(resolve => {
      setTimeout(resolve, 1000);
    });

    if(Math.random() < 0.5) {
      return new Error("I failed...")
    }

    return null;
  }),
  createNewStep("Last step", async () => {
    await new Promise(resolve => {
      setTimeout(resolve, 1000);
    });

    return null;
  })
]);

function createNewStep(title: string, fn: () => Promise<Error | null>): Step {
  return {
    title,
    state: "isPending",
    fn,
    error: null
  }
}

watch(jobSteps, async () => {
  for(const jobStep of jobSteps.value) {
    jobStep.state = "isInProgress"

    const error = await jobStep.fn();

    if(!error) {
      jobStep.state = "isSuccessful"
      continue;
    }

    jobStep.state = "isFailed"
    jobStep.error = error;

    // Queue failed...
    break;
  }
}, { immediate: true })
</script>

<template>
  <h1>Queue:</h1>
  <JobStep v-for="(step, index) in jobSteps" :key="index" :title="step.title" :state="step.state" :error="step.error" />
</template>
```

This is very basic and seems to work for my case but do you have any suggestions? Maybe this can be achieved far simpler using state management ( e.g. Pinia ). Never tried things like event busses and things like that.

I also think this approach is not tied to Vue and might also apply to other technologies if there is a common approach for this.